# How to list all built-in physical constants in Mathematica 11.3?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

There is an old description of a deprecated Mathematica package where all built-in physical constants are listed:
 https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PhysicalConstants/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html

It has been replaced by the `Quantity` package. The new one provides constants like "earth's gravity". However, listing all units using:

```
Quantity; Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules]
```

does not provide this one. So I have been wondering where to get an index or a list.

Is there a way to list all physical constants of the `Quantity` package?

Comment: Same question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1594175).

Comment: which is a different forum where I haven't got any answers yet.

Comment: It is customary to link crossposts to each other so people do not waste time answering a question that may have already been answered. There are responses to your question on the Wolfram Community site.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Knowledge Representation & Access](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/KnowledgeRepresentationAndAccess.html) functions like [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) and [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html).  All results are as at version 11.3.

First query all entities that have `"phys"` in there name as in "physical" or "physics".

```
Select[StringContainsQ["phys", IgnoreCase -> True]]@EntityValue[]
```

> ```
> {"FamousPhysicsProblem", "PhysicalConstant", "PhysicalSystem"}
> ```

This returns three entity types with `"PhysicalConstant"` being the best bet.  The properties available for these entities are:

All can be returned with

```
EntityValue["PhysicalConstant", "Name"]
```

For the particular entity for Earth's gravity.

```
EntityProperties["PhysicalConstant"]
```

> ```
> {"AbbreviationCode", "AlternateNames", "ASCIIDescription", "Classes", 
>  "ConjecturedValues", "Description", "EqualMagnitudeConstants", 
>  "EquivalentForms", "ExternalLink", "LevyLeblondClass", "Name", 
>  "PrimarySource", "Quantity", "SeriesExpansionValues", 
>  "StandardUncertainty", "StandardYear", "Value", "Values", "Variants", 
>  "VariantTable"}
> ```

The `"Classes"` property looks useful.

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Join@EntityValue["PhysicalConstant", "Classes"]
```

> ```
> {"Acceleration", "Cosmological", "Atomic", "CODATA", "Mass", 
> "Particle", "Spectral", "Astronomical", "Distance", "IAU", "Radius", 
> "Chemical", "Thermal", "Electric", "Dimensionless", "Exact", "Force", 
> "Frequency", "Magnetic", "Momentum", "Pressure", "Temperature", 
> "Time", "Speed", "WolframLegacyPackage", "Thermodynamic", 
> "AstronomicalAlmanac", "MassRatio", "CGPM", "Quantum", 
> "Gravitational", "Natural", "ForceRatio", "Coupling", "Radiation", 
> "Energy", "SolidState", "Length", "Area", "Volume", 
> "ParticleDataGroup", "Angle"}
> ```

`"Acceleration"` seems the best bet.

```
a = EntityClass["PhysicalConstant", {"Classes" -> "Acceleration"}]
EntityValue[a, "EntityCount"]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
EntityList[a]
```

> ```
> {"AccelerationAssociatedWithCosmologicalExpansionRate", "MONDConstant", "StandardAccelerationOfGravity"}
> ```

Now the entity can be selected by

```
grav = Entity["PhysicalConstant", "StandardAccelerationOfGravity"]
```

then

```
grav["Value"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[196133/20000, "Meters"/"Seconds"^2]
> ```

```
grav["ExternalLink"]
```

> http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?gn

Hope this helps.